# Wanting to Launch the Power User Tasks Menu on Windows 11 WINDOWS+X+U+S (FOR SLEEP 0)...SO CAN WAKE EASY MOVE MOUSE.. Does anyone have simple solution

Tags: wscript.shell

Wanting to Launch the Power User Tasks Menu on Windows 11 WINDOWS+X+U+S (FOR SLEEP 0)

This is so CAN WAKE Windows 11 EASILY VIA MOVE MOUSE.. Does anyone have simple solution?

Thanks in advance.

Tried this but does not work

Set Keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Keys.SendKeys("^{Esc}xu")

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, concise question.